# How create a v-model modifier to a VueJS Component?

Tags: vue.js

In VueJS there is some `v-model` modifies that pre-parse the binded value, for instance `v-model.trim` that removes whitespaces from the string.

How can I create my own modifier? for instance `v-model.myparse`
Today um using something like:

```
computed: {
  name: {
    get: function () { return parse(this._name);},
    set: function (value) { _name = parse(value);}
  }
```

What is very verbose.

I would it to be reusable to do something like:

```
<input v-model.myparse="name" name='n1'/>
<input v-model.myparse="name" name='n2'/>
<input v-model.myparse="name" name='n3'/>
<input v-model.myparse="name" name='n4'/>
```

computed properties with setters seems to do part of the work, but it is really useful with some few variables only, it becomes very verbose with a lot of properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, adding adding a custom modified to `v-model` is under [discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3666) but not yet implemented.

If it was implemented, you could extend the `v-model` and add a modifier to it.

Since that is not possible, you have a couple of options left, one of which is to use `:value` instead of v-model. Because `v-model` is just a syntactic sugar of following:

```
  <input type="text" :value="message" @input="message = $event.target.value">
```

The above code is the same as:

```
  <input type="text" v-model="message">
```

So, I suggest you replace the logic for the `@input` to something like this:

<input type="text" :value="message" @input="getModel">

Now, you can use a function to return a modified value as:

```
methods: {
  getModel ($event) {
    return $event.target.value.trim()
  } 
}
```

But all of what I mentioned can still be done with the `v-model` if you use a function.

Of course it goes without saying, you can create your own [custom directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) also.