# bind input with factor (v-model)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have a value which i want the user to modify, currently i have:

```
<input type="number" v-model="value" step="any"/>
```

but the internal value is radians, whereas i want the user to see and input a degree value.

so i want the displayed value(degree) to be bound 2-way with the internal value(radians) with a multiplication factor. how can i achieve this in vuejs?

in c# i would like to do smth like this:

```
float internalValue;
float factor = 3.141/360;
float externalValue {get {return internalValue/factor} set {internalValue=value*factor}};
```

can something similar be done with javascript, so it properly works with the v-model binding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How create a v-model modifier to a VueJS Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590952/how-create-a-v-model-modifier-to-a-vuejs-component)

Comment: You can use computed properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Computed property with get/set as mentioned in [VueJS documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter).

something like this:

```js
const factor = 3.141/360;

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    internalValue: '',
  },
  computed: {
    value: {
      get: function(){
        return this.internalValue/factor
      },
      set: function(val){
        let comp = val*factor
        this.internalValue = comp
        this.value = val
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  padding: 20px;
}


h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>input: </h2>
  <input type="number" v-model="value" step="any"/>
  <h3>
  ext. value: {{value}}
  </h3>
  <h3>
  int. value: {{internalValue}}
  </h3>
</div>
```

I've added it on JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/evyatarge/fhjmkudo/2/)

Comment: thank you for this answer & example, i did not know setters on computed properties are possible.
unfortunately, i am using this inside a v-for loop, where i am accessing a property of an array item, so using a computed property does not seem to be possible

Comment: i forgot to mention that i am iterating over an array in the question, otherwise your solution would be perfect

Answer (score 0):

as @Script47 linked, this answer helped me: [How create a v-model modifier to a VueJS Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49590952/how-create-a-v-model-modifier-to-a-vuejs-component)

functions in the vue module:

```
        degToRad(d){
            return d*Math.PI/180;
        },
        radToDeg(r){
            return r/Math.PI*180;
        }
```

in the html you can break the v-model down to :value and @input, which act similar to getter and setter of the input:

```
      <div v-for="item in items">
        <input class="val" type="number" @input="item.rotation = degToRad($event.target.value)" :value="radToDeg(item.rotation)" step="any"/>
      </div>
```